# Django rest-framework with React - blank page on frontend

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I have this code on my react `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
  inventory: []
 };

async componentDidMount() {
try {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/items/');
  const inventory = await res.json();
  this.setState({
    inventory
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
 }
}

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    {this.state.inventory.map(item => (
      //<div key={item.url}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{item.name}</h1>
        <span>{item.url}</span>
        <span>{item.price}</span>
        <span>{item.scalable}</span>
        <span>{item.taxable}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I'm using Django `react-framework`, I want to communicate from React frontend into my Django backend through the framework.

So, `inventory` is the name of the Django app. Which is registered on my `settings.py` file as `inventory`.

It has a model of course, and one of the classes of this model, is `item`, which, on my Django backend api, the `url` is defined as `items`. Like this `router.register(r'items', ItemViewSet)`.

It's like a list of all the products on the database. The typical rest-framework viewset.

Also, this is all serialized, and it's working well on the backend, if I access `http://localhost:8000/items/` it works, but the problem is the frontend, it just shows a blank page.

My index.js hasn't been edited, I have installed the Axios library, added the `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000",` line on my `packages.json` file.

Added also the `corsheaders` app in my settings.py file, I also have this declared on it:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
 'localhost:3000/'
)
```

But, it is still showing just a blank page from the react frontend (App.js).

What could be the cause?

Comment: open console , it will show errors if there are any

Comment: No errors on console, backend or frontend

Comment: Can you please check the network section if the API is being called? Also maybe try to update the code like: `this.setState({
    inventory: inventory
  });`

Comment: Are you sure that you have mounted the component to the DOM? Could you also show us the entrypoint?